# C++ I don't know how to find a word(eg.banana,sandwich) inside of a string(sentence) THE USER ENTERS the sentence and then write that word out

Tags: c++, string, char

I've tried this but I'm stuck honestly. 
I'm trying to find the first character, and then search for the ending of that substring (for eg. if the word is "sandwich" and it finds 's' that it figures out that its "sandwich") and then write out the word sandwich. And also I'm new to C++.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string s, word;
    char a;
    cout << "Enter the sentence that you desire: ";
    getline(cin, s);
    cout << "Enter the letter that you want: ";
    cin >> a;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
    {
        if (s[i] == a)
        {
            if (s[i] == '\0')
            {
                word = s;
                cout << word;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: if `s[i]` equals `a` it cannot equal `'\0'` at the same time (unless `a == '\0'`)

Comment: In other words, you want to find a beginning of a word (letter at the start of the string or after a whitespace or punctuation character). And if its first character matches, print that until the end of the word (the closest end of string, whitespace or punctuation). Otherwise skip to the next beginning of a word.

Comment: I suppose the first thing you have to figure out is what characters you consider to be word-characters. For instance, 'a', '-', and so on make up a word, but anything like '.' or space does not.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 you are correct Sir, but im really stuck don't know how to write the code out

Comment: @bitmask it needs to be a word like sandwitch, apple,bannana etc.

Comment: Suppose you were given the letter *first*, then you just starting reading words from `std::cin`. Would you be able to then print the first word that started with the prospect letter? Because if so, I suspect a [`std::istringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) and some thought will come in handy for this exercise. If you can do the first part then the only real problem is the order of input, and a string stream will help you solve that.

Comment: @WhozCraig That sounds like it could work, but im not given a word it is entered by a User but I don't know how to use stringstreams im quite new to C++ and programming

Comment: You need to read what I wrote again. Carefully. I understand you get the sentence/words *first*. I'm saying what if you were given the letter *first*. Would you then just read one word at a time from stdin, and as soon as you had a word starting with the letter you'd print it and stop? Certainly you can do that. So then the only problem is how to read the words from a full line you already read *before* the test char. And as I said, a `std::stringstream` will let you do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the end of a word with `std::find_if`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

template <typename Is>
std::string find_word(Is& stream, char needle) {
  auto const nonword = [](char c) {
    if ('a' <= c && c <= 'z') return false;
    if ('A' <= c && c <= 'Z') return false;
    if (c == '-') return false;
    return true;
  };
  for (std::string w; stream >> w;) {
    if (w.size() && w[0] == needle) {
      auto const last = std::find_if(std::begin(w),std::end(w),nonword);
      return std::string(std::begin(w),last);
    } 
  } 
  return "";
}
```

This takes any stream as argument, including `std::cin`, and can be invoked like this:

```
std::cout << find_word(std::cin,'w') << "\n";
```

It is important to specifically find the last character in each chunk handed you by the stream because the streams will only cut along whitespace by default. So if you enter a sentence:

```
Hello world!
```

You want the end of the word to be `'d'`, not `'!'`.

Answer (score 2):

The request is a bit foggy but given also the code you posted, i think i got a heck of what you intend to do.

The easiest (yet not necessarily the most performing one) is to use a stringstream, more precisely an [istringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/istringstream/?kw=istringstream).
You basically build it with a string (the one you passed from keyboard) and then you use it as if it was your cin (it acts as a normalized istream).

At that point you can iterate each word of the sentence and check the first letter.
The first character of a string is either myString[0] or myString.front(). That is up to you.

the code should look like this :

```
#include <iostream> //cin/cout
#include <sstream> //istringstream

using namespace std ;

int main()
{
    //first of all let's get our sentence AND the character you want
    cout << "insert sentence here: "  ;
    string sentence ;
    getline(cin, sentence) ;
    cout << "insert the character here: " ;
    char letter  ;
    cin >> letter ;

    //then let's create an istringstream with said sentence
    istringstream sentenceStream(sentence) ;    
    
    //let's then iterate over each word 
    string word ;
    while(sentenceStream >> word)
    {
        //and see if the word starts with the letter we passed by keyboard
        if(word.front() == letter)
        {
            cout << "the word \"" << word << "\" starts with '" << letter <<  "'\n" ;
        }
    }
    return 0 ;
}
```

Just a couple of hints:

1. iostream includes string already, there is no need to re-include it.
   [Edit] (as pointed out by [whozcraig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1322972/whozcraig), this does not follow the standard. guards will "negate" the double inclusion anyway, so yes, including string is not a mistake. as specified in the comment, i'm yet to find an implementation of iostream that does not include string)[/Edit]
2. It is good practice not to call a variable 's', or 'a': use a name
   that makes it recognizable.

Comment: (1.) is not guaranteed by the standard *at all*. If you use `std::string`, per the standard you gain access to it via including `<string>`. Period.

Comment: i am yet to find a single instance of an iostream not including string. but you are formally correct.

Comment: Thank you so much for the tips and you have solved my problem! @FRANCESCOAVANZI